# schema.org product tag incomplete

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I am getting "Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org." When validating my page with the Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

I have these properties defined:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmobi.victoriassecret.com%2Fbras%2Ffull-coverage&html=

Any ideas what I am missing? I looked and I don't see anything I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was my use of brand, when using brand you have to also tag it as an itemtype of organization:

```
<div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
```

Comment: I had the same problem as @bshack.  I added this to my code and it now validates:     <div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">[BRAND NAME]</span></div>